# Facebook ExecuteAndWait

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

If I use asynch call the application function but not like I want. 
If I use the synch call the application doesn't function and crashes when I launch it.
(Unable to resume activity: NetworkOnMainThreadException)
Why??

```
private void makeFBRequest(final Session session) {
           Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
               if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                    if (user != null) {
                       Profile.name = user.getFirstName();
                       Profile.surname = user.getLastName();
                       Profile.email = (String) user.asMap().get("email");
                }
            }   
        });     
        //request.executeAsync();   
          request.executeAndWait();
    }
```

Comment: Because you can not do Network call from UI(Main) thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved that problem introducing these lines before the call.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: it works, but could you explain why? Thankyou

Comment: This is bad Idea to run connect with server in main thread. I'd smash developer's  hands for such.